# Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted ERROR when uploading a photo

Tags: php, upload, rotation

I have a little problem with my website.

People use this page to create a post on my site, you can attach photos to it.
All photos were working ecept that one. ( see below for the link )

When I try to upload it on the "post" page it says:

My girlfriend is the one that is trying to upload it , before uploading it she rotate the picture with windows 7 ( in preview mode ) so the image would be on the right side.

PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 3411201 bytes) in /home/(rest of path)/upload.php on line 65

line 65 on upload.php = $tmp=imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth,$newheight);

I've been looking for a way to "counter" that error for 2 days.

Can anybody help me please?

It only show that error with that image, I don't know if the rotate is the problem...

Thank you very much

Comment: Script / image size is bigger then your PHP settings allow

Comment: Like I said bellow, if I change these settings will it change site performance?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Allowed+memory+size+of

Comment: I wouldn't touch the memory_limit - restrict the upload photo size to X MB - this is how serious websites deal with this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your script is running out of memory.  Right now it seems that you have ~64mb allocated per PHP script.  It is amazing that it is using more than that (unless you are uploading huge photos!), but what happens when you put the following at the top of your script?

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '128M');
```

This will raise the memory limit temporarily for that script.  If you find that you need to allocate more memory for your script, then you'll have to change the value in php.ini if you don't want to use `ini_set()`.

Does it work or does it run out of memory ~128mb?

---

**NOTE:**
If this is a personal project, this solution is ok. If this is something bigger than that, I would take matino's advice and limit your upload size.

Comment: I can't change it...  still giving me the error if I add your line in my script and I cant change the ini.php memory size "variable"

Comment: WOW you are amazing,, it does work!!, I added the script to post.php instead of upload.php , working now!!

Comment: Even if I resize it to 800x600? cause the big photo is only "temp" photo so I can resize it, max size is 5mb right now , so 5mb is normaly 1600x1090 and + but I resize it to 800x600 so is that ok?

Comment: 5mb is fine, I'm more so talking about 100mb+ files.  But your script would probably run out of memory again if someone tried that.  Doesn't mean you should ignore that scenario though.

Comment: Alright thank you, limit is 5mb so yea it will warn them before happening, thank you very much for help guys!

Answer (score 2):

Try to use smaller photo or increase your memory_limit in php.ini

In php.ini:
change value of memory_limit like this:
memory_limit = 258M
Restart web server.

Comment: Is this going to affect the site performance? or it doesn't matter ?

Comment: You are in control of your site performance, not the memory_limit of your php. If you mindful of memory usage then you will be fine.

Comment: It's your server, you can set memory limit to whatever you want/need