# Allowed memory size exhausted on a 6MB photo upload

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, file-upload, amazon-s3

I'm trying to let my users upload a photo to my webserver, make a thumbnail out of it and then upload both to amazon s3 servers.

For some reason when trying to upload a 6mb image, the server logs:

```
Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 17280 bytes)
```

Why is my code taking up so much memory for a 6MB? is this normal? maybe I need to know of a way to clear memory somewhere in my code before moving to the next part?

I know I can increase my allowed memory but it seems like a non healthy way to solve this. I'm looking for a different approach by using less memory.

This is my upload.php file the I use with a jquery upload on an html page. The html page is calling the upload.php via ajax.

upload.php:

```
$valid_exts = array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif'); // valid extensions
$max_size = 8000 * 1024; // max file size (8MB)
$path = 'uploads/'; // upload directory

if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' )
{
    if( @is_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']) )
    {
        // get uploaded file extension
        $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($_FILES['image']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
        // looking for format and size validity
        if (in_array($ext, $valid_exts) AND $_FILES['image']['size'] < $max_size)
        {
            // unique file path
            $path = $path . *******. '.' .$ext;
            $secret = ********;
            $imgname = 'useralbums/'.$wedding_id.'/'.$wedding_id.'_'******'.'.$ext;
            $thumbname = 'useralbums/'.$wedding_id.'/'.$wedding_id.'_'******'_thumb.'.$ext;

            $tempthumb = 'temp.'.$ext;

            // move uploaded file from temp to uploads directory
            make_thumb($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $tempthumb, 250, $ext);
            $status = array();
            $binary = file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], true);
            $status['img'] = saveFileInS3($imgname, $binary);
            $binary = file_get_contents($tempthumb, true);
            $status['thumb'] = saveFileInS3($thumbname, $binary);
            $category = 'Reception'; // TO DO: Catch categories

            if (add_wedding_photos($status['img'],$status['thumb'],$wedding_id, $category)) {   $status['db'] = 'OK';   }

            unlink($tempthumb);
        }
        else {
            $status = 'Upload Fail: Unsupported file format or It is too large to upload!';
        }
    }
    else {
        $status = 'Upload Fail: File not uploaded!';
    }
}
else {
    $status = 'Bad request!';
}

echo json_encode(array('status' => $status));



function make_thumb($src, $dest, $desired_width, $ext) {
    if ($ext == 'jpg' || $ext == 'jpeg') {
            $source_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);      
    }
    if ($ext == 'png') {
            $source_image = imagecreatefrompng($src);       
    }
    if ($ext == 'gif') {
            $source_image = imagecreatefromgif($src);       
    }   
    /* read the source image */
    $width = imagesx($source_image);
    $height = imagesy($source_image);

    /* find the "desired height" of this thumbnail, relative to the desired width  */
    $desired_height = floor($height * ($desired_width / $width));
    $desired_height = 250;

    /* create a new, "virtual" image */
    $virtual_image = imagecreatetruecolor($desired_width, $desired_height);

    /* copy source image at a resized size */
    imagecopyresampled($virtual_image, $source_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $desired_width, $desired_height, $width, $height);

    /* create the physical thumbnail image to its destination */

    if ($ext == 'jpg' || $ext == 'jpeg') {
            imagejpeg($virtual_image, $dest);       
    }
    if ($ext == 'png') {
            imagepng($virtual_image, $dest);        
    }
    if ($ext == 'gif') {
            imagegif($virtual_image, $dest);        
    }

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted ERROR when uploading a photo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7740968/allowed-memory-size-of-67108864-bytes-exhausted-error-when-uploading-a-photo)

Comment: I've read everything I could find on it. everyone recommends increasing the memory limit - thats exactly what i dont want to do... :/

I'm looking for a way to clear memory in the process.

Comment: 8000 * 1024 * 4 = 128,768,000 bytes, that's just for loading the image into memory; and you're resizing so you also need to allow memory for the resized image at 4 bytes per pixel, plus PHP's own memory needs

Comment: The only way to avoid this is not resizing / loading the image in PHP but offloading it to an external library. Else you should increase the memory limit. See @MarkBaker comment for the calculation...